# The number of $5$ digit numbers that can be formed with digits $1,2,3,4,5,6$ if the number must include $1$ and $2$ is___

Tags: combinatorics

The number of $5$ digit numbers that can be formed with digits $1,2,3,4,5,6$ if the number must include $1$ and $2$ is

(1) $6^5 – 2.5^5 + 4^5$

(2) $10.5^4$

(3) $20.5^4$

(4) $5.4^5$

My approach is as follow
[image]

Let us take a case where we select 2 number viz. $1$ and $2$ and it can be rearranged as ${}^5{C_2} \times 2! = 20$ with three space vacant now six number can be rearranged in 3 vacant space as $3^6$ hence the answer is $20 \times {6^3}$ but official answer is $1$.

Where my solution is wrong as I consider the condition that repetition is allowed as $1$ and $2$ are included.

Comment: The rules are not clear.  Is repetition allowed or not?  If not, you can do it directly.  If it is allowed, then Inclusion Exclusion is probably the way to go.

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand your approach, but it looks like you're overcounting; for instance, it looks like you would count the number $12133$ more than once. Hint: it might be easier to count the numbers that *don't* contain both $1$ and $2$. (Another hint: are you by any chance studying the inclusion-exclusion principle?)

Comment: yes i got it number are counted double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Chris Lewis, you counted some combinations more than once.

The total number of all 5-digit numbers is $6^5$.
Let $A$ denote the set of numbers without 1, $B$ denote the set of numbers without 2, then the number of 5-digit numbers that must include 1 and 2 is
$$6^5-|A\cup B|=6^5-(|A|+|B|-|A\cap B|)=6^5-(5^5+5^5-4^5)=6^5-2\cdot 5^5+4^5$$

Comment: Note that $A \cap B$ is the set of numbers that include neither $1$ nor $2$.